# Adding Multiple NSArrays to NSMutableDictionary with corresponding matching item in array order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have two arrays say itemName and itemImages

```
NSArray *itemName = @[@"Blog", @"Missions", @"Subscriptions", @"Questions", @"Aide",@"Disconnect"];
NSArray *itemImages = @[@"ico-1",@"ico-2", @"ico-3", @"ico-4", @"ico-5", @"ico-6"];
```

I need to add them to a dictionary

```
 NSMutableDictionary *menuItemNameImage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [menuItemNameImage setValue:itemName forKey:@"itemName"];
 [menuItemNameImage setValue:itemImages forKey:@"itemImages"];

 NSLog(@"%@", menuItemNameImage);
```

But this makes the following Dictionary

```
{
    itemImages =     (
        "ico-1",
        "ico-2",
        "ico-3",
        "ico-4",
        "ico-5",
        "ico-6"
    );
    itemName =     (
        Blog,
        Missions,
        Subscriptions,
        Questions,
        Aide,
        Disconnect
    );
}
```

What I rather want is some think like this :

```
{ 
  { 
    itemImages = "icon-1",
    itemName = Blog
  },
  { 
    itemImage = "icon-2",
    itemName = "Missions"
  }, ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get that structure with a single `NSDictionary` - you need an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects.

Here is how you can do it:

```
NSMutableArray *menuItemNameImage = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0 ; i != itemNames.count ; i++) {
    [menuItemNameImage addObject: @{
        @"itemName" : itemNames[i]
    ,   @"itemImage" : itemImages[i]
    }];
}
```

Comment: thks ... the edited answer works perfectly ...  Lucas answer works too ... but your solution is better in terms of code clarity

Comment: Actually, this code is preety much the same thing: an array of dictionaries. The only difference it's because he didn't check for the bounds of `itemImages` array, so it will cause a crash if `itemImages.count > itemNames.count`. Without the check, you can create the dictionary with the two items at once, but you do have to ensure that the arrays will always have the same lenght

Answer (score 2):

What you could use is a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`. Each dictionary would have two entries: an `itemImage` and `itemName`.

It would be something like this:

```
NSArray *itemName = @[@"Blog", @"Missions", @"Subscriptions", @"Questions", @"Aide",@"Disconnect"];
NSArray *itemImages = @[@"ico-1",@"ico-2", @"ico-3", @"ico-4", @"ico-5", @"ico-6"];

NSMutableArray *menuItemNameImage = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < itemName.count; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *itemNameImage = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    itemNameImage[@"itemName"] = itemName[i];

    //just a precaution if the array os images is smaller than the ones of names, to avoid unwanted crashes
    if (i < itemImages.count) { 
        itemNameImage[@"itemImage"] = itemImages[i];
    }

    [menuItemNameImage addObject:itemNameImage];
}

NSLog(@"%@", menuItemNameImage);
```

The output, as you want:

```
(
    {
        itemImage = "ico-1";
        itemName = Blog;
    },
    {
        itemImage = "ico-2";
        itemName = Missions;
    },
    {
        itemImage = "ico-3";
        itemName = Subscriptions;
    },
    {
        itemImage = "ico-4";
        itemName = Questions;
    },
    {
        itemImage = "ico-5";
        itemName = Aide;
    },
    {
        itemImage = "ico-6";
        itemName = Disconnect;
    }
)
```

You can access the elements like this, for example:

```
NSString *firstItemName = menuItemNameImage[0][@"itemName"]; 
NSString *firstItemImage = menuItemNameImage[0][@"itemImage"];
```