# How to add multiple dictionaries with for loop?

Tags: ios, swift, loops, dictionary

I want to add multiple dictionaries into the one. I have the next loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    parameters["universityID"] = universityIDs[i]
    parameters["fieldOfStudy"] = fieldOfStudies[i]
}
```

I want the result like this:

```
newParameters = [[1: "Smth"], [2: "Smth"], ... ]
```

I cannot try

```
newParameters = [
    // for loop here
]
```

how can I achieve this? May be it's a silly question, but I'm just tired and cannot find the solution =/

Comment: Refer this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501422/adding-multiple-nsarrays-to-nsmutabledictionary-with-corresponding-matching-item

Comment: If you use the same key in every iteration of the loop, you will end up with `parameters["universityID"] = arrayLength - 1` and `parameters["fieldOfStudy"] = arrayLength - 1`. The question needs more clarity.

Comment: I wonder why would you need an array of dictionaries with a single entry on each instead of a single dictionary with all your entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to end up with an array of dictionaries. If so, do this:

```
let universityIDs = [1,2,3,4]
let fieldOfStudies = ["some", "test", "studies", "data"]
var newParameters: [[Int: String]] = []
let arrayLength = universityIDs.count
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    let parameters: [Int: String] = [universityIDs[i]: fieldOfStudies[i]]
    newParameters.append(parameters)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add anything to `newParameters` after creating it as long as it is declared as variable (keyword `var`, as opposed to `let` which creates constants).

When iterating on your arrays, all you have to do is to call `appendElement()` to add a new entry inside `newParameters`:

```
var newParameters = [[Int:String]]()

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    newParameters.append([universityIDs[i] : fieldOfStudies[i]])
}

// newParameters now contains [[1: "smth"], [2: "smth"]]
```

Comment: I did: `var parameters = [[String: String]]()` and appended to it, but at the end it returned me empty value `[]`

Comment: Can you add the line where you append to your question? Otherwise, be aware that arrays and dictionaries are structures and are then copied when affected. If you pass `parameters` as an argument to a method and modify it inside the method, it will still be empty when returning since only the copied instance will be modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 arrays

```
let universityIDs = [1,2,3]
let fieldOfStudies = ["Technology", "Arts", "Math"]
```

you can combine them like this

```
let results = zip(universityIDs, fieldOfStudies).map { [$0.0:$0.1] } // [[1: "Technology"], [2: "Arts"], [3: "Math"]]
```